# How to apply min/max attribute to v-model in Vue?

Tags: validation, input, vuejs2

Current constraint of `min` and `max` are not respected due to the way `v-on` is implemented:

```
<input id="passwordLength"
       class="form-control form-control-sm"
       type="number"
       min="5"
       max="35"
       v-model="options.length">
<span class="input-group-btn" v-on:click="options.length+=1">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </button>
</span>
```

#### Question

How can I respect the constrain and still keep an elegant implementation?

Answer (score 3):

You could add a custom modifier to the `v-model` directive:

```
// function that gets the min and max values for the element and prevents the value of the model from going below the min or above the max
function bindNumberInRange(el, binding, vnode) {
  let model = binding.expression;
  let min = parseInt(el.min);
  let max = parseInt(el.max);
  let val = parseInt(binding.value);

  if ((min !== NaN) && (min >= val)) {
    vnode.context[model] = min;
  } else if ((max !== NaN) && (max <= val)) {
    vnode.context[model] = max;
  }

  el.value = val;
}

// get the original reference to the v-model directive
let modelDirective = Vue.directive('model')

// set a new definition of the v-model directive
Vue.directive('model', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) { 
    // first fire the original v-model bind hook
    modelDirective.bind(el, binding, vnode);

    if (binding.modifiers.range) {
      bindNumberInRange(el, binding, vnode)
    }
  },
  componentUpdated: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    // first fire the original v-model componentUpdated hook
    modelDirective.componentUpdated(el, binding, vnode);

    if (binding.modifiers.range) {
      bindNumberInRange(el, binding, vnode)
    }
  }
})
```

Then, all you would need to do is add a `.range` modifier to `v-model` when you want the model to respect the `min` and `max` attributes of the affected element:

```
<input type="number" min="4" max="10" v-model.range="foo">
```

Here's a [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qredme).

Here's Vue's (semi-lacking) [documentation on directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

Comment: The problem is that you can not really type a number, set it to min 4 and max 15 and now you can not type in 13 because firstly you type 1 and its changed to 4 and then you type 3 which is 43 and thats changed to 15 :(.

Comment: Doesn't work: `Error in directive model bind hook: "TypeError: modelDirective.bind is not a function"` -_-

Comment: How would this code look if I say have a foo object which contains two or more values? for example: foo: { value1: 0, value2: 3, value3: 5 }?

Comment: I tried it here but it doesn't work as expected:
https://codepen.io/olle-olsson/pen/gOaLJmg

Answer (score 1):

Use @Focus to apply a max & min number validation to your :rules. Make sure to set the max with large default number. Both max & min default will be updated upon focusing on that specific input box. (This text-fields are being created with a loop)

```js
<v-text-field type="number" 
  @focus="validateWhenFocused(item)"
  :rules="numberRules"
  :label="item.questionName"
  v-model="item.value"
  outline>
</v-text-field>

export default {
  data() {
  return {
    numberRules: [
    v => !!v || "Input is required!",
    v =>
      v < this.maxLength ||
      `${this.errorName} must be less than ${this.maxLength} numbers`,
    v =>
      v > this.minLength ||
      `${this.errorName} must be greater than ${this.minLength} numbers`
    ],
    maxLength: 100,
    minLength: 0,
    errorName: "",
  },
  methods: {
    validateWhenFocused(item){
    this.maxLength = item.maxValue
    this.minLength = item.minValue;
    this.errorName = item.questionName
  
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something basic:

#### Usage

```
<span class="input-group-btn" 
    v-on:click="options.length=decrement(options.length, {min: 5, max: 35})">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

#### Service Tests

```
import test from "ava";
import formValidator from "../src/services/form-validator";

test("formValidator.increment()", t => {
  t.is(formValidator.increment(1, { min: 0, max: 10 }), 2);
  t.is(formValidator.increment(9, { min: 0, max: 10 }), 10);
  t.is(formValidator.increment(10, { min: 0, max: 10 }), 10);
  t.is(formValidator.increment(-1, { min: 0, max: 10 }), 0);
  t.is(formValidator.increment(-5, { min: 0, max: 10 }), 0);
  t.is(formValidator.increment(5, { min: 0 }), 6);
});

test("formValidator.decrement()", t => {
  t.is(formValidator.decrement(2, { min: 0, max: 10 }), 1);
  t.is(formValidator.decrement(1, { min: 0, max: 10 }), 0);
  t.is(formValidator.decrement(0, { min: 0, max: 10 }), 0);
  t.is(formValidator.decrement(-1, { min: 0, max: 10 }), 0);
  t.is(formValidator.decrement(15, { min: 0, max: 10 }), 10);
});
```

#### Service Code

```
export default {
  increment(value, { min = 0, max }) {
    let newValue = value + 1;

    if (newValue < min) return min;
    if (typeof max === "undefined" || newValue <= max) return newValue;
    return value;
  },
  decrement(value, { min, max }) {
    let newValue = value - 1;

    if (newValue < min) return min;
    if (newValue > max) return max;
    if (newValue >= min) return newValue;
    return value;
  }
};
```