# How to limit digit number in vue input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My goal is to limit the number of digit user can enter in the input field. So a user can only input 10 digits. I tried min and max still doesn't work

Here's the code

```
        <input
          v-model="amount"
          type="number"
        >


        <script>
             export default {
                  data() {
                      return { 
                          amount: 7800
                      }
                   }

              }

        </script>
```

Right now i can add more than 10 digits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply min/max attribute to v-model in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285895/how-to-apply-min-max-attribute-to-v-model-in-vue)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We can control the value of `<input>` manually:

```
 <input
  type="number"
  :value="amount"
  @input="updateValue"
/>
```

and check in updateValue method:

```
  data() {
    return {
      amount: 7800
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(event) {
      const value = event.target.value
      console.log(value, this.amount)
      if (String(value).length <= 10) {
        this.amount = value
      }
      this.$forceUpdate()
    }
  }
```

Note that `this.$forceUpdate()` is used to make component re-render when user input more than 10 characters.

Demo on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/MdwNdX)

Comment: This doesnt work if i put v-model="amount" which I need to put

Comment: I updated the answer. `v-model` is a shorthand for `:value` and `@input`

Comment: I see, weird that v-model doesnt work for @input but :value does work thanks

Comment: This answer solved my issue, but I can't run away from a thought that this is a hack. Documentation says `If you find yourself needing to force an update in Vue, in 99.99% of cases, you’ve made a mistake somewhere.`. Is there a better way to solve this issue in 2021?

Answer (score 33):

Replace this:

```
<input v-model="amount" type="number">
```

to

```
<input v-model="amount"
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
        type = "number"
        maxlength = "10"
/>
```

Comment: Great, been searching for this for several hours.

Answer (score 2):

Put a condition on Updated, checking the digits, if surpasses it, cut it. I did something similar, but for max value, not digits, but i think its the same logic:

```
updated() {
    if (this.album.max_colorized > this.maxPictures) {
        this.album.max_colorized = this.maxPictures;
    }
}
```

This way if it surpasses the max, change to max.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this inline:

```
<input type='number' v-model='trademark' class='form-control' @input="trademark = trademark.slice(0,10)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in 2023 and I realized that there's no need to listen to an input event or use the updated hook.

Simply use the `maxlength` attribute for form inputs. An example of usage is:

```
 <input type="text" maxlength="10" v-model="myModel" />
```

If you need the length to be dynamic, then use this:

```
<input type="text" :maxlength="max" v-model="myModel" />

data: () => ({
      max: 10
 })
```

Comment: OP can't just use maxlength because their input type is number.

Comment: @ChristineTreacy have you been able to limit the digit number on the input field? I believe it would also work on input type of number

Comment: I came looking for a solution because maxlength does not work when they input type = number. Here's the solution I posted: <input type='number' v-model='trademark' class='form-control' @input="trademark = trademark.slice(0,10)"/>

Comment: wow this looks great @ChristineTreacy. please share the link to the post so I can give an upvote

Comment: Thanks! Glad it worked for you. It did post it the other day. Appreciate the upvote! https://stackoverflow.com/a/76092625/12488167

Comment: Awesome. You're welcome Christine

Answer (score 1):

`maxlength` works with `type="text"` it seems not to work only with `type="number"` and it was designed this way. So if it doesn't matter you could go with `type="tel"` and it should be ok, otherwise only JS